# How to modify salesforce Organization data by code in any way

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, integration, metadata-api

I know we can't modify the organization (company information) via apex, but is there any other way by which we can do that, like via any API call or anything? Actually in my requirement I would like to modify the default locale info and address of the organization object via code.

Comment: I've re-opened this as I think it's pretty clear what it's asking and it'd be good to have some suggested solutions.

Comment: Thanks Matt, for reopening this. Well I figured out the solution by myself.  Anyway thanks

Comment: that's good news! Can you post an answer below so that others may benefit in the future?

Answer (score -3):

```java
User u = [select name,LocaleSidKey from User where ID =: userId];
u.LocaleSidKey = 'IN'; //set abbreivation of country name for which you want to set.

update u;
```

Comment: Did you try that, because DML operation are not supported on organization object via apex.

Comment: @JagdeepJuneja Adding an explanation to your code would help identify if this is a valid solution and why this should solve the problem.

Comment: This question is about the default locale and organization address, not individual user locale.

Comment: The question is about the organization. Your answer is about the user. Please explain how it answers the SoP question